# Magento1.9 - add block to product page

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, product-page

Seems a standard use case but I didn't find a working solution, so I post it here.

In `base/default/layout/catalog.xml` I see:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            ....
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I need to add a block within the `product.info` block, so in my local.xml I tried:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/product_view" name="sticazzi" as="sticazzi" template="catalog/product/view/sticazzi.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

and in my `view.phtml` I put:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sticazzi') ?>
```

This does not work, what's wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is half correct change `type="core/product_view"` to `type="catalog/product_view"`

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="sticazzi" as="sticazzi" template="catalog/product/view/sticazzi.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

If you use `<reference name="content">` this will load the block without `getChildHTml`

Comment: sorry, I did exactly what you wrote here and it does not work. my question is wrong, I will update it.

Comment: catalog/product_view not core/product_view

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display it in **view.phtml** then you need to use of that reference block like below

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="sticazzi" as="sticazzi" template="catalog/product/view/sticazzi.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Now you can use it in **view.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sticazzi') ?>
```